# Can not drop/change a view

Tags: postgresql

I've got a view which accidentally (don't know how) lost it's name.

Now I can not drop it any longer because pgadmin III throws an error
Error: syntax-error at the end of input 
Line 1:DROP VIEW public

Trying to rename it causes the error 
Error: syntax-error at "to"
Line 1:ALTER TABLE RENAME TO NewName

The view definition is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  AS 
 SELECT ...
   FROM table a;


ALTER TABLE OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE  TO postgres;
```

Comment: Have a look a this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23836/how-to-list-all-views-in-sql-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a backup of the database, restrored it.

In the new database the invalid, nameless view has been dropped by pgadmin.